# Can i have multiple versions of VMWare PowerCLI in single machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware, powercli, vcenter

In Single Windows Machine, can i have multiple versions of PowerCli installed?

Stay for example. I like to have one version for 5.1 and another version of powercli for 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not officially, PowerCLI will automatically upgrade older versions of itself.